# When implementing a text search on an SQLite database, when is it best to use full text search and when is using LIKE in the SELECT query best?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm writing an Android app which allows the user to store information in an SQLite database.  It is a relatively simple database with 9 tables and most users will store less than 200 records in the main table, but a few may store up to 1000.

An important function of the app will be to provide the user with the ability to search for a string in any of nine different fields across several of the tables.

There appear to be two approaches: full text searching using an FTS table, and using the WHERE ... LIKE function in the SELECT statement.  I've searched stackoverflow and googled it, but have been unable to find any real information about which is best to use under which circumstances.

It would be very useful to understand the pros and cons of each method.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use sqlite with fts4

two search tables

one tables is full text search table with one column
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE %s USING fts4(content);
one tables is data table with the column which you define.

this method can extend easily in the future.